# Как удалить дубликаты по условию?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, group-by

Есть DataFrame

|  | city | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Лодзь | 990 |
| 1 | Краков | 990 |
| 2 | *NaN* | 990 |
| 3 | Перм | 1826 |
| 4 | *NaN* | 1826 |
| 5 | *NaN* | 1827 |

Нужно удалить дубликаты по колонке `year`, но в случае если поле `city` не пусто, то такие значения не удалять.

Ожидаю увидеть:

|  | city | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Лодзь | 990 |
| 1 | Краков | 990 |
| 3 | Перм | 1826 |
| 5 | *NaN* | 1827 |

Я думала над таким вариантом, но тогда я удаляю дубликаты и среди значений где колонка `city` не пуста:

```
df=df.sort_values(by=['city'])
df=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['year'])
f=df.sort_values(by=['year'])
```

Comment: Ну я бы сгруппировал по году, посчитал записи и приджойнил этот счётчик к основному фрейму по полю год. После этого просто оставляете в датафрейме те записи, где либо этот счётчик = 1 либо city не NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

решение по [описанию уважаемого CrazyElf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1342461/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B8#comment2377468_1342461):

```
res = (df
       .assign(x=df.groupby("year")["city"].transform("nunique"))
       .query("""city == city or x == 0""")
       .drop(columns="x"))
```

результат:

```
In [37]: res
Out[37]:
     city  year
0   Лодзь   990
1  Краков   990
3    Перм  1826
5     NaN  1827
```